# Merge multiple column in one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas data frame where the total of first column is done in second column and same for the second and third column:

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3  
 0     3                         
 1     2                         
 2     1       6                 
 3             7        13
```

What I want to do now is merge all the columns (1,2,3) into one column A (ignoring the total value) like this:

```
     Column A      
 0      3                         
 1      2                         
 2      1                        
 3      7
```

How could I best approach this issue? Here is the code mentioned below.

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'Column1':[3, 2, 1, ""],
        'Column2': ["", "", "6", "7"],
        'Column3':["", "", "", 13]}

abc = pd.DataFrame(data)

abc

abc.to_dict()
```

My Output:

```
{'Column1': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: ''},
 'Column2': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '6', 3: '7'},
 'Column3': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: 13}}
```

Comment: Are empty values `NaN` or empty string i.e `''`? Please add `df.to_dict()` to the question.

Comment: The empty values are empty strings ' '

Comment: kindly share the source dataframe as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict()``

Comment: Edited my question and put the code with converting data frame to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace to missing values empty strigs, then back filling missing values and select first column, last convert to integers if necessary and to one column `DataFrame`:

```
data = {'Column1':[3, 2, 1, ""],
        'Column2': ["", "", "6", "7"],
        'Column3':["", "", "", 13]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df.replace('', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].astype(int).to_frame('Column A')
print (df1)
   Column A
0         3
1         2
2         1
3         7
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solved my problem!